# Align multiple equations with text

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, intertext

I have 4 equations (2 on each line) separated by text. I cannot get the equal signs (red box) to align.
Here is the code to recreate the image:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \eta_{1 i}=x_{1 i}^{T} \beta \qquad \quad \eta_{2 i}=x_{2 i}^{T} \alpha
\end{equation*}    
where
\begin{equation*}
    \theta_{1}=h_{1}(\eta_{1 i}) \qquad \quad \theta_{2}=h_{2}(\eta_{2 i})
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

I have tried with alignedat but cannot find a way to include the text "where" to be left justified

```
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
        \eta_{1 i}&=x_{1 i}^{T} \beta \qquad \quad &\eta_{2 i}&=x_{2 i}^{T} \alpha\\
        \theta_{1}&=h_{1}(\eta_{1 i}) \qquad \quad &\theta_{2}&=h_{2}(\eta_{2 i})
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `alignat*` and the command `\intertext` or `shorintertext` of `mathtools`:[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \eta_{1 i}&=x_{1 i}^{T} \beta \qquad \quad &\eta_{2 i}&=x_{2 i}^{T} \alpha\\
\shortintertext{where}
    \theta_{1}&=h_{1}(\eta_{1 i}) \qquad \quad &\theta_{2}&=h_{2}(\eta_{2 i})
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply `align`? No need to specify the horizontal spacing.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I should have used `align`. I used `alignat` only because `alignedat` was used in the question...